# Anaconda Navigator Removed Itself

Tags: python, anaconda

I went on to my computer today to work on a code I had been chiseling away at for school. I clicked on my anaconda navigator, only for anaconda to quickly show up in my running task bar at the bottom of my screen then disappear. I read on a other post that perhaps my Macbook wasn't updated and that was affecting it. I updated my Macbook and when I went to my launchpad to open Anaconda, it had completely disappeared. I tried opening a terminal and running "Anaconda-navigator" and I got this:

```
(base) xxxxx-MBP:~ xxxxx$ anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 199, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 7, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 205, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

I'm quite concerned, as my code was important for school and I can't access it. I tried installing it, but it said Anaconda was still downloaded, but it is nowhere to be found in my downloads or applications. Also, I ran the command to show my packages and they were still installed.

Comment: Looks like `conda` (anaconda's packages and environments manager) is still installed as your prompt has the `(base)` prefix. Why did you needed anaconda navigator for? You can likely start your editor or any program you used from the command line.
If you want it back, try `conda install anaconda-navigator`.

Comment: I come across this issue today. I use Navigator to remove one of my environment, but it instead removed Anaconda itself...... this is a ironic bug..... hopefully Anaconda can fix this asap....